# JsonConverter does not contain a definition for DefaultSettings

Tags: c#, json.net

I am getting error when I try to set `DefaultSettings` of `JsonConverter`.

```
JsonConverter.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
};
```

So basically it does not find DefaultSettings in JsonConverter.

The weird thing is the same code was working earlier, I cleared the cache of the nuget package and restored them and then it stopped working

Now even when I see the metadata of the `JsonConverter` I do not see the `DefaultSettings` there

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
JsonConvert`er`.DefaultSettings
```

You actually want [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm) (minus the `er`)

> Gets or sets a function that creates default JsonSerializerSettings.
> Default settings are automatically used by serialization methods on
> JsonConvert, and ToObject () and FromObject(Object) on JToken. To
> serialize without using any default settings create a JsonSerializer
> with Create().

**Example**

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
};
```